# Ms access form: field order

Tags: forms, ms-access

can I somehow set in what order the text fields become active after pressing the "Tab" button?

I think it depends on when you added the field and not where it is in the form. So can I change this or I should add the fields in the order I want to switch them with the "Tab" button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways to change tab order.
With the form in design view, right click on an area of the form without a control. On the context menu that appears, click on Tab Order. A dialog will open that will allow you to change the tab order.
Another method is via the property sheet for each control. On the Other tab there is a property for Tab Order. Just set it to whatever you like.